# merge elements from list of tuples if the first array is the same

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples:

```
seqList=[('SQ010', ('sh001', '1-10')), ('SQ010', ('sh002', '5-15')), ('SQ010', ('sh003', '6-16')), ('SQ010', ('sh004', '7-17')), ('SQ020', ('sh001', '8-18')), ('SQ020', ('sh002', '9-19')), ('SQ020', ('sh003', '10-20'))]
```

I want to merge every element with the same first array to have this output :

```
[('SQ010', ('sh001', '1-10'), ('sh002', '5-15'), ('sh003', '6-16'), ('sh004', '7-17')), ('SQ020', ('sh001', '8-18'), ('sh002', '9-19'),('sh003', '10-20'))]
```

I have tried with groupby with the following code:

```
from itertools import groupby
output_list = [tuple(i[1] for i in e) for _, e in groupby(seqList, lambda x: x[0])]
print output_list
```

it result:

```
[(('sh001', '1-10'), ('sh002', '5-15'), ('sh003', '6-16'), ('sh004', '7-17')), (('sh001', '8-18'), ('sh002', '9-19'), ('sh003', '10-20'))]
```

I don't understand why I loose the SQXXX part and how to have the desired output. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQXXX` part is the `_` variable that you have gotten rid of. Try:

```
output_list = [(i,) + tuple(i[1] for i in e) for i, e in groupby(seqList, lambda x: x[0])]
```

Giving:

```
[('SQ010', ('sh001', '1-10'), ('sh002', '5-15'), ('sh003', '6-16'), ('sh004', '7-17')), ('SQ020', ('sh001', '8-18'), ('sh002', '9-19'), ('sh003', '10-20'))]
```